# Which is better way in magento2 for social login?

Tags: magento2, magento-social

I have used inchoo module extension for social login in magento1

Now i want to migrate my project into magento2

There are not available inchoo module for social login in magento2

So i have tried mageplaza social login module but both database system(data storing system) is very different

So how can i migrate my magento1 data into magento2

Have anyone tried before it?

Comment: You can use mageplaza free social extension for magento2  [Mageplaza Free extension](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-social-login-extension/google-plus-login.html)

Comment: @AskBytes yes i am using it. But how can migrate data from magento1 because that time i have used inchoo module which 's database structure are different

Comment: i think only way to do Data migrate by manual mysql queries since DB structures are different. Or try to modify the mageplaza social login module to use your existing DB tables.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there can be 2 ways to fulfill your requirements:

**Way #1:**

- Install a third party extension (like mageplaza social login or scommerce social login as already mentioned above)
- Analyse the table structure of Inchoo Social Login extension for Magento 1 and the one you install for Magento 2
- Export the data from Magento 1 database, convert it in the format acceptable by the Magento 2 module
- Import it in the Magento 2 database

**Way #2:**

- Analyze the module of Magento 1
- Write your own module based on the table structure used in Magento 1 module

If I would have such a situation, I would prefer the second way, since I have the complete code of Magento 1 and I know how to write a module in Magento 2. I would just need to do the same as it was in Magento 1.